# How to obtain a list of attribute translations from OLAP cube?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I want to get a list of atrribute translations from our cube, so we can see potentially missing translations.

I've tried $system.MDSchema_levels, but can't see specifically where translations are made.

```
SELECT *
FROM $system.MDSchema_levels
WHERE CUBE_NAME  = 'DWH OLAP'
AND LEVEL_CAPTION <> '(All)'
```

Help would be aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no Translation information at SSAS Management Views. You have to use Microsoft AMO for that, writing a program on .NET. Please find a [code sample](http://sasokoren.com/export-list-of-ssas-objects-and-translations-using-amo-in-net/) doing almost your task, and [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/analysis-management-objects/programming-amo-olap-advanced-objects#Transl) on AMO.